# Multiple versions of the app: with and without AD

Tags: android, gradle, admob, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have an app that use AdMob, and I want to create a pay version of the app with no AD. I did the followings:

In the **build.gradle**:

```
 productFlavors {
    freeVersion {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_PRO", "false"
        minSdkVersion 15
        applicationId 'com.myapp'
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1'
    }
    proVersion {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_PRO", "true"
        minSdkVersion 15
        applicationId 'com.myapp.pro'
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1'
    }
}
```

In the **ActivityMain**:

```
   private boolean isPro = BuildConfig.IS_PRO;
```

Now, if **isPro** is true, I will hide the AD, otherwise I will show it. Is this right? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about gradle, but if you're doing an ad-free version of your app, I'd recommend removing your ad networks more thoroughly.
Chances are AdMob (or any other ad network) will do a whole lot of unnecessary dialling home with analytics data and caching adverts ready for use.

It's more respectful of your premium customers for you to remove the ad network entirely from their build. i.e. Don't disable the code that displays the advert, instead you should refrain from linking in the ad networks library altogether.

Comment: I'm trying to following your suggest, but if I use freeVersionCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0', than I have an error on the ActivityMain, even if I created an ActivityMain for the **freeVersion** flavor, without any reference to AdMob.